# Get new object from another class nodejs

Tags: node.js

Ok so I have a class that contains

**Object JS**

```
var GameServer = require("./GameServer");
var gameServer = new GameServer();
```

GameServer() contains

**GameServer JS**

```
function GameServer() {
    // Startup
    this.run = true;
    this.lastNodeId = 1;
    this.lastPlayerId = 1;
    this.clients = [];
    this.largestClient; // Required for spectators
    this.nodes = [];
    this.nodesVirus = []; // Virus nodes
    this.nodesEjected = []; // Ejected mass nodes
    this.nodesPlayer = []; // Nodes controlled by players
}
```

Now, what im trying to acheive is getting gameServer from ObjectClass

In my class i've tried

**new JS**

```
var ObjectClass = require("./ObjectClass");
var gameServer = ObjectClass.gameServer;
```

But from this way, I won't be able to grab the class GameServer() properties. I'm new to node and im sorry I have to ask this question. I'm currently stuck right now

When I try to grab clients from GameServer

```
var ObjectClass = require("./ObjectClass");
var gameServer = ObjectClass.gameServer;
gameServer.clients.length;
```

I get error, clients is undefined. Any way around this?.

**I cannot modify GameServer nor Object js.**. Basicly im making a script attacthed to a script for extra functionalities.

Comment: Needs more code. Especially what `otherclass` is, and probably how it is created.

Comment: Do you have the classes in the exports ?

Comment: If you need to create objects you could probably use the factory pattern, otherwide is ok exporting a new Object per file, as require js cache the output of the file.

Comment: No, The object class does not contain an export. It only has a variable that creates a new function of GameServer. Im trying to get that variable since Object js stores its own values in the new GameServer. Im trying to get that variable, and its values of GameServer

Comment: Well, seems like the exports is empty, so you are getting an empty object when you do `require('./GameServer')`, you should add the Gameserver function to the exports, same with the ObjectClass

Comment: How would I do that? I'm new to node. Sorry. GameServer has an export, but how would I use it or add a GameServer function export?

Comment: Sure, you could find more information about the module of nodejs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the exports of your files so when doing require(file) you're getting and empty object {}..

For gameServer you should be doing something like:

```
'use strict';
function GameServer() {
    // Startup
    this.run = true;
    this.lastNodeId = 1;
    this.lastPlayerId = 1;
    this.clients = [];
    this.largestClient; // Required for spectators
    this.nodes = [];
    this.nodesVirus = []; // Virus nodes
    this.nodesEjected = []; // Ejected mass nodes
    this.nodesPlayer = []; // Nodes controlled by players
}

module.exports =  exports = GameServer;
```

ObjectClass

```
'use strict';
var GameServer = require("./GameServer");
var gameServer = new GameServer();
exports.gameServer = gameServer;
```

You need to understand that require cache the value returned by the file, so you would be using a singleton of gameServer.

Comment: module.exports =  exports = GameServer; ??

Comment: I'm glad it is working for you. Just for clarification, I do `module.exports = exports = gameServer` just to ensure the exports variable points to the same object that module.exports, as we are overriding the reference of exports, so exports is pointing to a different object. At the end you could use module.exports only forgetting of exports

Comment: Is there a way to do this without adding exports to the Object Class? My main goal is not to modify the other classes.

Comment: Not sure what other classes you mean. Nodejs have a simple module loader, so to access each module node developers use require ( some other decide to use another module loader ), in this case when you 'require' a js file, node put a module object to the file, contains a lot information, the important property for us here is exports, so when you require a file, the exports property is returned. So, no there is no way to require a file returning a value with out using the exports property.